# Backfill user objects with new omniauth-twitter attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, omniauth

I have a rails application that uses omniauth-twitter to allow users to signup. Previously, I was only getting the user's name and id from Twitter.

I just added a migration and updated the user model to now request the user location, user image url, and user profile url. These attributes are working for all *new* users, but I have a few hundred users who signed up prior to adding these attributes. **How can I backfill all users to grab the attributes that have been added after they signed up?**

Comment: Provide a link in user's profile that will authorize them again. (Use `force login` or `authorize` option in omniauth-twitter)